# xpath: search "down" and then back "up"

Tags: xml, xpath

I'd like to search for a value in nodes, then traverse back up an unknown number of levels to another kind of node.

For example, I'd like to find the names of all corporations that are located in France or have a subsidiary in France.  Subsidiaries could be nested several levels.

I know I can traverse up with

```
//location[text() = 'France']/..
```

but what if I want to keep traversing up until I get to a particular node?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <corporation>
      <name>Fromage Sarl</name>
      <location>France</location>
   </corporation>
   <corporation>
      <name>Cheese Inc</name>
      <location>USA</location>
      <subsidiary>
         <name>Yankee Imports</name>
         <location>France</location>
      </subsidiary>
   </corporation>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This xpath:

```
//corporation[location = 'France' or .//subsidiary/location = 'France']/name
```

selects all the `corporation/name` in the whole document only for those `corporation`s that have child `location='France'` or any descendant `subsidiary/location = 'France'`

Output selected nodes shall be:

```
<name>Fromage Sarl</name>
<name>Cheese Inc</name>
```